# How to solve the given differential equation $xg(f(x))f'(g(x))g'(x)= f(g(x))g'(f(x))f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions such that $\forall x\in\Bbb R$ and $f(x),g(x)>0$,
>
> $$xg(f(x))f'(g(x))g'(x)= f(g(x))g'(f(x))f'(x)$$
>
> Also,
>
> $$\int_0^x f(g(t)) \,dt= \frac{1-e^{-2x}}{2}$$
>
> If $g(f(0))=1$ what is $f(g(0))+g(f(0))$?

This is absolutely a new kind of problem to me, so my tries just include trying to put $x=0$ and trying to find any pattern of sorts but it isn't quite getting me anywhere, and tried differentiating the given integral and I get $f(g(x))g'(x)=e^{-2x}$. What is the proper way to solve this?

Comment: Just for fun you can also solve for $g(f(x))$. (Maybe it's a second part to this exercise; not sure why else the first condition would be included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the derivative of the integral $$f(g(x))=e^{-2x}$$So when $x=0$, $f(g(0))=1$ and what you want the answer is $2$.